# onBindview Holder of RecyclerView is not working for second position but i have count three in getItemCount

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Iam getting data from firebase and it is populated in `userMessageList.adapter` is notified and `getItemCount` is showing correct count but `onBindViewHolder` only run once for 1st postion of userMessage list. `onBindViewHolder` is not working for further `positions or data`

i have got no solution related to my problem

> THIS IS MY ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    private List <Messages> userMessagesList;
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase,users;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Messages> userMessagesList){

        this.userMessagesList = userMessagesList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_messages_layout,viewGroup,false);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder, int i) {



        String messageSenderID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Messages messages = userMessagesList.get(i);

        String fromUserID = messages.getFrom();
        String fromMessageType = messages.getType();

        users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fromUserID);

        users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")){

                    final String receiverImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(receiverImage)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image)
                            .into(messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage);


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        if(fromMessageType.equals("text")){

            messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if(fromUserID.equals(messageSenderID)){

                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_messages_layout);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                messageViewHolder.senderMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());
            }
            else{

                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.receiverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_messeges_layout);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                messageViewHolder.receiverMessageText.setText(messages.getMessage());


            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userMessagesList.size();
    }


    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView senderMessageText, receiverMessageText;

        public CircleImageView receiverProfileImage;


        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            senderMessageText =itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_message_text);
            receiverMessageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_message_text);
            receiverProfileImage =itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_image);

        }
    }
}
```

> THIS IS ACTIVITY CODE WHERE IAM POPULATING THE userMessageList

```
rootRef.child("Messages")
                .child(messageSenderID).
                child(messageReceivedID)
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot 
                 dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                 Messages messages =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        messagesList.add(messages);
                        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

    }
```

Comment: do not put network calls in onBindView that is very poor practice....download all your data and call preload images so that they load faster.

Comment: i have tried by excluding but still not working

Answer (score 0):

As Pemba Tamang in comment above rightly said you should not have any network or database related code in your adapter.

Algorithm to solve your problem:
1. Fetch list of Messages outside of adapter.
2. Subscribe for child change outside of adapter.
3. When child changed go to view model, find this Message by it's id and update this info. 
4. Update your adapter

Also will be good if you will update your adapter with DiffUtils. It will bind only changed child, not all. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil

Comment: Can you please edit this code for me. i did not find the solution